# Sticky navigation script wont attach class to div

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, sticky

I am currently editting a wordpress theme and creating a navigation bar half way the page that sticks to the top of the screen once the user scrolls past a certain point. Ive done this before and it worked fine. I copied that exact code and changed the #divs and classes to the correct ones. This is the code i use:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  console.log($(window).scrollTop())
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
  $("#stickbar-steps").addClass("after-scroll-wrap");
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() < 9) {
  $("#stickbar-steps").removeClass("after-scroll-wrap");
}
});
```

However it doesn't seem to add the class to the #div.When i manually add the class to the #div it works fine but it just wont load the script or wont attach the class. Usually when i reach that point in my previous working one, i could see it getting attached using inspect element, but im not seeing it in this one.

The wordpress theme  has a seperate page in the admin section which allows me to paste in JS code. I've tried to add it there and i've tried to paste a copy among the other jquery files in the functions.php. But neither of them seems to work.

Any ideas where to look for? Theme uses jquery ver=1.12.4.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide your markup and any necessary CSS as well? From looking at the code, if the scrollTop value is equal to 9 or 10 neither of your functions would run. I recommend updating both of those to greater than or equal to 10, and less than or equal to 9, respectively.

Comment: ive put them in jsfiddle. Hope this helps. https://jsfiddle.net/h2fto4Ly/1/
Im gonna fiddle around with it there as well.

Comment: @Josh I changed it to work in the fiddle. No idea why it doesnt work on the live site though. I copied the html from inspect element, copied the css from the css file and i tried to add the jquery in multiple ways (one of them being among the javascript files and the other in the field in the wp-admin that was made for it.)

Comment: So it's still not working on your site? Can you confirm that the jQuery is loading on your site by running a simple jQuery code snippet?

Comment: @josh i found out what the problem was. instead of it using $ it was using JQuery. I just had to swap out the dollar signs for JQuery and it worked...Thanks for your help though. I appriciate it.

Comment: glad you got it working!